# lowering default gcp quotas for different resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, quota

I would like to grant access to a GCP project to a new user, but I would like to limit quotas for this user for specific resources, e.g. user can run VMs with max 8 vCPUs and not more, or VM can have only 16GB of ram and not more or user can attach only SSD with 100GB max.

I've found in docs that default quotas can be raised (after contacting Google support)
https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas

The question is, can the quotas for resources (like vCPU, RAM, storage, SSDs, etc) can be lowered?

Best regards
Michal

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, by default all projects start with the same quotas, which you can change by [requesting additional quota](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/quotas#request_quotas). Unfortunately, there aren't any ways to lower default quotas upon projects creation as of now and also it's not possible to halt the historical learning which makes these default quotas grow over time.

From the [Google Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), you can submit a "Feature Request" on this.